# Как получить с помощью js список ссылок с символом якоря

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

На странице есть ссылки вида `<a href="#link1"></a>`

Прописываю в js скрипте код

```
anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']")),
```

или

```
anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')),
```

но ничего не возвращается в итоге и ошибок в консоли не видно.
Мне нужно решить эту проблему без применения jquery

Answer (score 2):

```js
var anchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']")];
console.log(anchors);
```

```html
<a href="#link1"></a>
```